# Access CloudSQL while Deploying to Flexible PHP AppEngine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, google-app-engine, doctrine

I've been able to deploy an example Symfony 3 app to a Google AppEngine Flexible PHP app following the [example here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-symfony-on-appengine-flexible). I then added the CloudSQL APIs to the project and the entries in `app.yaml` so when I SSH into an instance, I can see the MySQL socket in `/cloudsql/`.  I then added the Doctrine bundles to the Symfony project, setup a couple models, etc., tested locally successfully, and tried to redeploy the app to Google.

When the deploy process runs composer, it's running the `symfony-scripts` entries defined in `composer.json`. Some of those routines need to access the database apparently but that's failing. I'm getting `An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` errors from the `clearCache` script. If I remove that entry from `composer.json` and retry, I get the same error from the next script.

I'm beginning to think that the socket that connects to the database may not be configured during the `app deploy` process. Has anyone tried to do something like this before and gotten it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

[Why does a composer update need access to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461393/why-does-a-composer-update-need-access-to-the-database)

Adding `server_version: 5.7` under `doctrine` `dbal` in my `app/config/config.yml` fixed this. It no longer tries to connect to the database during `composer install` and the app deploys now.